# Stop attending [events]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[events](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/events) is a flexible, undefined meta tag with so many uses:

- system actions
- programming triggers or actions (covered by [vba] and other programming tags)
- calendar activities  (covered by specific calendar application tags)
- Task Scheduler tasks (covered by several existing specific tags)
- social activities
- labels on pictures that were taken at social activities
- Excel data that happens to represent something called "events"

It is probably worth creating a [system-events](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-events) tag because those questions relate specifically to using system events as a trigger or capturing information from system events, so the abstraction of an "event" conveys meaning about a certain kind of task.

The rest should be retagged with existing tags or removed where irrelevant.  The [events](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/events) tag, and its synonomized [event](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/event) tag can be deleted.